# Get price of in-app purchase item for android app to display to the user

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, in-app-purchase

I'm using the following library for integrating in app purchase in my android app:

https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3#getting-listing-details-of-your-products

I want to get the price of in-app items to display to the user. If I use the `getPurchaseListingDetails()` method from the library, a `List<SkuDetails>` has to be returned from which I can extract the price. But only a null is returned for my code.

```
BillingProcessor bp;

ArrayList<String> arrayListOfProductIds;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shop);

    arrayListOfProductIds = new ArrayList<>();

    arrayListOfProductIds.add("level_unlock");
    arrayListOfProductIds.add("hint_buy");
    arrayListOfProductIds.add("hint_level");

    boolean isAvailable = BillingProcessor.isIabServiceAvailable(this);
    if(isAvailable) {
        bp = BillingProcessor.newBillingProcessor(this, "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAz0mDL13z6FtY0Xy09ru0LST4pgy4ph6smeHEsaFbX8fZYVR6SM+eHSIA3j+DnUhiRK8QTun/VJdRnbovvX25rrMju3unAqJzur5whB/4OSXoh6YLOp5+UBiAPuQEzOFsmVhJlwZVH8ScjjwveqXmkByaTde4Ca/FrSoQpbFcuGY0BJPfSSxaQzjs9pwbhNpUqAXF3pbay4/B4o0tw9+rK/8qcGW2ZbG2V/VPQzMZKKBKfyCogY2YV37q80s8CP3tqBzbbnLOF9pmji3A/iuRheclfVuFjj1p7keXMUch2kPPrRJVtLcDbR8gBG0Gju/27zCIaFzFG2RWeu45Qkw5uQIDAQAB", this);
        bp.initialize();
    }

    LinearLayout backButtonShop = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.back_button_shop);
    backButtonShop.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button priceButton01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.price_button_01);
    priceButton01.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button priceButton02 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.price_button_02);
    priceButton02.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button priceButton03 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.price_button_03);
    priceButton03.setOnClickListener(this);

    List<SkuDetails> purchaseListingDetails = bp.getPurchaseListingDetails(arrayListOfProductIds);
    priceButton01.setText(purchaseListingDetails.get(0).currency + purchaseListingDetails.get(0).priceValue);
    priceButton02.setText(purchaseListingDetails.get(1).currency + purchaseListingDetails.get(1).priceValue);
    priceButton03.setText(purchaseListingDetails.get(2).currency + purchaseListingDetails.get(2).priceValue);

    }

}
```

I get a null pointer exception at `priceButton01.setText(purchaseListingDetails.get(0).currency + purchaseListingDetails.get(0).priceValue);`
this line because `purchaseListingDetails` is null.

How do I make it return the `List<SkuDetails>` instead of null ?

Comment: HI Anand, as already answered you can get id when you create one in play console.

Comment: Thanks Rishab. Is there a specific pattern I should use for the product ID ? Like "com.anjlab.test.iab.s2.p5" this that is mentioned in the answer. Can I just use this pattern and use p1, p2, p3 for my 3 products ?

Comment: You are free to use any pattern . Should be unique . Normally people keep it similar to package name followed by what your in app is about

Answer (score 0):

That is because the product ID you entered is not valid. Product IDs should look something like this `"com.anjlab.test.iab.s2.p5"` .

Comment: How do I get this type of product ID for each of my items?

Comment: From your Google play console

Answer (score 0):

This answer is late but seeing that it has no accepted answer I'll give a possible solution:

- Your product IDs ("level_unlock" etc..) does seem valid
- Try to put your code under the following method:

  ```
  @Override
  public void onBillingInitialized() {
  <your code here>
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

you need to perform this chunk of code:

```
List<SkuDetails> purchaseListingDetails = bp.getPurchaseListingDetails(arrayListOfProductIds);
    priceButton01.setText(purchaseListingDetails.get(0).currency + purchaseListingDetails.get(0).priceValue);
    priceButton02.setText(purchaseListingDetails.get(1).currency + purchaseListingDetails.get(1).priceValue);
    priceButton03.setText(purchaseListingDetails.get(2).currency + purchaseListingDetails.get(2).priceValue);
```

inside `onBillingInitialized()` method, not in `onCreate()`.